# Find consecutive free numbers in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a table, containing numbers (phone numbers) and a code (free or not available).

Now, I need to find series, of 30 consecutive numbers, like 079xxx100 - 079xxx130, and all of them to have free status.

Here is an example how my table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE numere
(
    value int,
    code varchar(10)
);


INSERT INTO numere (value,code)
Values
 (123100, 'free'),
 (123101, 'free'),
...
 (123107, 'booked'),
 (123108, 'free'),
 (...
 (123130, 'free'),
 (123131, 'free'),
 ...

 (123200, 'free'),
 (123201, 'free'),
...
 (123230, 'free'),
 (123231, 'free'),
 ...
```

I need a SQL query, to get me in this example, the 123200-123230 range (and all next available ranges).

Now, I found an example, doing more or less what I need:

```
select value, code
from numere
where value >= (select a.value
                from numere a
                left join numere b on a.value < b.value 
                                   and b.value < a.value + 30 
                                   and b.code = 'free'
                where a.code = 'free'
                group by a.value
                having count(b.value) + 1 = 30)
limit 30
```

but this is returning only the first 30 available numbers, and not within my range (0-30). (and takes 13 minutes to execute, hehe..)

If anyone has an idea, please let me know (I am using SQL Server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like it works in my dataset. Modify the select and see if it works with your table name.

```
DECLARE @numere TABLE
(
value int,
code varchar(10)
);


INSERT INTO @numere (value,code) SELECT 123100, 'free'

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @numere)<=30
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @numere (value,code) SELECT MAX(value)+1, 'free' FROM @numere
END

UPDATE @numere
SET code='booked'
WHERE value=123105

select *
from @numere n1
inner join @numere n2 ON n1.value=n2.value-30
    AND n1.code='free'
    AND n2.code='free'
LEFT JOIN @numere n3 ON n3.value>=n1.value
    AND n3.value<=n2.value
    AND n3.code<>'free'
WHERE n3.value IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, finding me 30 consecutive free numbers.
I guess, finding from 00-30 range only, i will do it manually, because i will not have so many ranges avialable :).
If someone have a quick way to find them from 00 ( i would think like a substr function, cuting the last digits, then check if they are within the 0-30 range.

Comment: Not understanding the latter part of your comment. Also, how was the performance compared to the method you originally used?

Comment: Regarding peformance, i have tested now only in a dummy sqlite database, tomorrow i will check with production database. But it looks that is the same performance, more or less.
Regarding my comment, this is a real use case, some company (with 30 employes), want to have all their numbers, being like 079xxxx00-079xxxx30, (the last 2 digits, from 0 to 30 ) and i need to select from the database, if there are free numbers, within this range.
Anywhay, your answer is already extremley usseful as it is it is . Thanks

Comment: Oh! You could simply add "and n1.value like '079%00'"

Answer (score 1):

This is usual Island and Gap problem.

```
; with cte as
( 
    select  *, grp  = row_number() over (order by value)
            - row_number() over (partition by code order by value)
    from    numere
),
grp as
(
    select  grp
    from    cte
    group by grp 
    having count(*) >= 30
)
select  c.grp, c.value, c.code
from    grp g
    inner join cte c    on  g.grp   = c.grp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query table data for gaps between booked numbers using following SQL query where [SQL LEAD() analytical function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lead-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-next-value.aspx) is used

```
;with cte as (
 select
  value, lead(value) over (order by value) nextValue
 from numere
 where code = 'booked'
), cte2 as (
select
 value gapstart, nextValue gapend,
 (nextValue - value - 1) [number count in gap] from cte
where value < nextValue - 1 
)
select * 
from cte2
where [number count in gap] >= 30
```

You can check the SQL tutorial [Find Missing Numbers and Gaps in a Sequence using SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/find-missing-numbers-gaps-in-sequence-of-numbers-using-sql.aspx)

I hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

Can't Test it at the moment, but this might work:

`SELECT a.Value
 FROM (SELECT Value
                  FROM numere
                  WHERE Code='free'
                ) a INNER Join
                 (SELECT Value 
                  FROM numere
                  WHERE code='free'
               ) b ON b.Value BETWEEN a.Value+1 AND a.Value+29
GROUP BY a.Value
HAVING COUNT(b.Value) >= 29
ORDER BY a.Value ASC`

The output should be all numbers that have 29 free numbers following (so it's 30 consecutive numbers)

Comment: Thanks, this one works,  displaying only the values, not also the codes ( i am very new to SQL, but i will try to modify, so i get in output both columns).